# Consulta SQL con c#

Tags: c#, sql

Estoy realizando un programa en c# y realizo esta consulta:

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow Dgv_datos in dgv_prehoras.Rows)

"SELECT MAX(MV_TTRBJDO) FROM AHMOVS1 WHERE MV_NUMEMP = '" + Dgv_datos.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "' AND MV_FECHA BETWEEN @desde AND @hasta"
```

Recorro los datos de un datagrdiview con un foreach.

El select sí funciona, pero sólo me trae el valor máximo obviamente. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que me traiga toda los campos de esa consulta y no solo el campo maximo?

Comment: Creo que tendrías que agregar el resto de columnas al `SELECT` pues no los noto

Comment: Porque estas pidiendo solo ese dato. Deberias llamarlos a todos, por ejemplo: "SELECT MAX(MV_TTRBJDO), valor2, valor3, ..., valorN FROM..."

Comment: Dado que usas una función de agrupàmiento `MAX` entonces aparte del `SELECT` con todas las columnas deseadas, deberás hacer `GROUP BY` de esas mismas columnas del `SELECT` menos la que calculas con `MAX`

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me fuciono. Lo que hize fue vaciar la consulta a un datatale y con otro foreach recorrer todos los valores. Encerio muchas gracias.

Comment: Te sugiero anotar la solución como respuesta y marcala como respuesta aceptada. Saludos